# How can I pass the data of one array into another array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a program where the user can load an array with strings, and then the strings in positions that are multiples of 2 and 3 need to be added to a new array. I'm not sure how to do this, since I can't assign arrays. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{
    int i;
    char strings[5][256];
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    scanf("%s", strings[i]);
    }
    char strings2[5][256];
    int k = 0;
    {
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)}
        if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i % 3 == 0))
        {

            //Here's where I would do strings2[k] = strings[i] if it were possible
        k=+1;
        }
    }   
}
```

What can I do?
EDIT: I added these lines:

```
if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i % 3 == 0))
        {
        strcpy(strings2[k], strings[i]);
        k=+1;
        }
        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
         printf("%s\n",strings2[i]);
        }
```

The problem now is random symbols get printed instead of letters.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `string.h` functions?

Comment: Why are your arrays strings though? You can't perform mathematical operations on strings, so you would have to convert them to integers. Also you're checking if i is a multiple of 2 or 3, not index of i.

Comment: @Nina: The question doesn't require any math.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question most likely.

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed

Comment: Don't use `k=+1`.  Use `k += 1`, or `k++`.  `k=+1` is equivalent to `k = 1` which isn't what you want.

Comment: There are no *"multiples of 2 and 3"* between 0 & 4?? `if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i % 3 == 0))` will never test true in that case (other than for `0` with is a multiple of neither except for the trivial case).

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy(strings2[k], strings[i]);`

Should get you there.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Comment: I don't even know how you made sense of the code and the question...

Comment: @nina: `//Here's where I would do strings2[k] = strings[i] if it were possible`

Comment: This seems to work but when I try to print the elements in strings2, they come up looking like weird characters instead of letters. Maybe I can edit the post to show exactly what I added.

Comment: Are your new strings (the ones you copied) null-terminated?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: You can manually check it by looping through the "strings" (which are arrays of characters) and checking for '\0' which is the Null character. All C strings need to be terminated with it or you can get garbage output. If you want to try your hand at this without using <string.h> I would suggest trying to copy the strings by using a for loop to copy them one character at a time.